# Change structure url of Yii Framework

Tags: php, url, yii, yii-routing

URL standard of Yii is : `http://www.example.com/index.php?r=watch`Can I change this URL to `` `http://www.example.com/watch?v=6Pddo6kCxvM `` (it's same youtube url)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look into using `mod_rewrite` in your `.htaccess` file for that.

[Here you go](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/)

Comment: Are you aware that in frameworks everything is routed to `index.php` and from there internal routing is used?

Comment: Yes I am. I haven't used Yii but I have used various MVC frameworks (and made one.) This change can be made with mod rewrite.

Comment: I haven't used it either... and no. Or Yii sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In addition to using .htaccess/mod_rewrite for getting the webserver to invoke the proper script, you should also look into configuring the URL manager. It's covered in the Special Topics: [URL Management](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)